# Page with Multiple Loops Breaking Pagination

Tags: pagination, loop

I made a customized index.php so that I have multiple loops on the same page so that the content can be displayed differently. I got this to work, however the pagination is broken. Despite several hours of Googling and trying all sorts of things, I can't get it to work. Subsequent pages just display the same thing as the home page.

I'm also using the WP-PageNavi plugin to do the pagination at the bottom. Each subsequent page is correct in the address bar and at the bottom of the page according to the plug-in, but the content is the same on every page.

I understand that you cannot have 'paged' and 'offset' at the same time, but I have absolutely no understanding of how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- First Loop -->
    <div id="first-post">
        <?php
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query('showposts=1'.'&paged='.$paged);

        ?>

        <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>    

        <?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "1") { break; } else { ?>

                        <!-- post stuff -->

                     <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

        <?php $count1++; } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div> <!-- close first-post -->

    <!-- Second Loop -->
    <ul class="two-col">
    <?php
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query('showposts=4'.'&paged='.$paged);

    ?>

    <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=1'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "4") { break; } else { ?>
             <li>
                        <!-- post stuff -->
    </li>
    <?php $count2++; } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul> <!-- close two-col -->
    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

    <!-- Third Loop -->
    <ul class="three-col">

    <?php
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query('showposts=6'.'&paged='.$paged);

        ?>
    <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&offset=5'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php static $count3 = 0; if ($count3 == "6") { break; } else { ?>

    <li>

                        <!-- post stuff -->

    </li>

    <?php $count3++; } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul> <!-- close three-col -->

    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

    <!-- End All Looping -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The content is the same because the loops are the result of the `get_posts()` call which does not take into account the page you are on. In short you are not looping through the results of your `WP_Query` but instead the `get_posts()` . Try replacing `get_posts` and the `foreach` with a `while` loop using the results of `WP_Query` .

Each of your loops should be of the form:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
//display contents here
endwhile;
```

For you purpose, `$args` would be `'showposts=4'.'&paged='.$paged` where `$paged` is the page you are on.

If you are simply trying to output your posts with the first 1 styled one way, the next 5 styled another etc. It is probably best to have only *one* loop and but use some if statements inside to format the posts appropriately.

(NB if you are attempting to have several loops on one page, all of which paginate: without a bit of effort, that won't work. Since there is only one `$paged` variable for all the loops. )

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. Sorry if I sound ridiculous but I'm still new to php. How can I use an if statement to just change posts 2-4 and 5-12, but all be on one loop? That would be the ideal solution but I don't know how to do it. Thanks so much again.